# Can I use semicolons to delimit statements in LilyPond?

Tags: music

In LilyPond, I only have seen statements delimited by line breaks. Can you use semicolons instead?`\header{title = "A scale in LilyPond"};\relative {c d e f g a b c};\version "2.16.2";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just separate the statements by whitespace. Replacing the semicolons by spaces in your example should work.